# Strange scooping rules in for loop with lambda in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, lambda, scope

How come this does not compile:

```
  for(size_t i;;)
    auto Lambda = [](size_t i) {};

1>application_src\general_experiments.cpp(96): error C2365: 'i' : redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'
1>          application_src\general_experiments.cpp(95) : see declaration of 'i'
```

...when this compiles:

```
  for(size_t i;;) {
    auto Lambda = [](size_t i) {};
  }
```

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: They both compile with gcc 4.7.2/4.8.1 and clang 3.2, so I suggest a bug in VC++

Comment: I suspected something like that, thank you